# Webpack how to get dependency list for a given entry point

Tags: webpack

I need the list of files that are dependent on a particular entry point that's supplied to the web pack. Currently, I am using stats object to get this list. To get access to stats object we need to create a bundle. is there a way to get the list without creating the bundle?

Comment: Are you using the ES6 module syntax? If so, that opens some options.

Comment: Yes. I am using es6 module syntax

Comment: Ok. You could look into tools like https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge then. Let me know how it goes and I'll upgrade this to an answer if needed.

Comment: I tried this and its not giving the deeper dependency tree madge -f es6. If you look at the webpack dependency tree it goes way deeper based on your imports and returns all the dependencies

Comment: Ah, yeah. Obviously not all dependencies are in ES6 format yet even if your own code is. This is a hard problem. I guess you would have to dig the answer from the source. I'm afraid there might not be a simple way to avoid generating a bundle.

Comment: Did you ever look into creating a webpack plugin to do this specifically?

Comment: No, i didn't create a plugin to do this instead I used dependency list from jsonstats. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I use https://github.com/dependents/node-dependency-tree for the same purpose and it works great.